# Child component not re-rendering after state change in Promise..?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a function within a react child component that makes a HTTP post request. In its response I've used this.setState and this.forceUpdate however the component does not re-render.

I've used this.setState and this.forceUpdate however the component does not re-render. If I put the alert method in the response it works, it's just not re-rendering

```
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: "https://56gbghdghgbbg&start="
        + start.format() + '&end=' + end,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: test,

        })
        .then(function (response) {
        this.setState({savePlaylist: "Saved Playlist",})
        //this doesn't cause a re-render

        })
        .catch(function (error) {


        });

      }
```

Expected the child component to re-render...Nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://56gbghdghgbbg&start=' + start.format() + '&end=' + end,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data: test
})
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ savePlaylist: 'Saved Playlist' });
    //this doesn't cause a re-render
  })
  .catch(error => {});
```

Change the callback function to the arrow function.

You will be not able to access this.setState inside the callback function, the scope of the function is different.

OR you can do this as I have mentioned below

```
let self = this;
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://56gbghdghgbbg&start=' + start.format() + '&end=' + end,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data: test
})
  .then(function(response) {
    self.setState({ savePlaylist: 'Saved Playlist' });
    //this doesn't cause a re-render
  })
  .catch(function(error) {});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. 
why did it require the arrow function?

Comment: If you use arrow function you can able assess the this.setState. If not you will not able to access the this.SetState. If you don't want to use the arrow function you can use the first program, I just want to tell you there is another way to do it.